# Moving 1/2 a Vector to Another Vector in deque implementation

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am working on implementing `pop_front()`/`pop_back()` member functions for a deque that does not use vector's erase function in the code. Basically, here is the task:

- For `pop_front()` if `vecOne` is empty, the first half of the elements from `vecTwo` are moved to `vecOne`, then `pop_back()` on `vecOne` is called.
- For `pop_back()` if `vecTwo` is empty, the first half of the elements from `vecOne` are moved to `vecTwo`, then `pop_back()` on `vecTwo` is called.

I have written the following code, but it doesn't work in all cases:

```
template <class T>
void Deque <T>::pop_front()
{
    if (vecOne.empty() && vecTwo.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    if (vecOne.empty()) {
        if (vecTwo.size() == 1) {
            vecTwo.pop_back();
        } else {
            for (int i = (vecTwo.size()-1)/2; i > -1; --i) {
                vecOne.push_back(vecTwo[i]);
                vecTwo[i] = vecTwo.back();
                vecTwo.pop_back();
            }
            vecOne.pop_back();
        }
    } else {
        vecOne.pop_back();
    }
}
```

E.g. Let's say the first vector, `vecOne` has no elements but `vecTwo` has 5 `(60, 70, 80, 90, 100)`. In this code I will get the following result:

`vecOne` has the numbers 60, 70, and 80 in that order (which is what I should get)
`vecTwo` has the numbers 100, and 90 (which is out of order).

I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong if I am trying to get the first 1/2 of the elements from `vecTwo` to move to `vecOne` then leave the remaining `vecTwo` elements alone while `pop_back` the last element on `vecOne` which is the front of the deque.

Comment: Why are you inventing your own deque? The `std::deque` implementation (which is optimal) is based on ring buffer, an efficient way to handle this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

It is because vecTwo does not have even number of elements.
So what happens is:

vecTwo is split in {50, 60, 70} to be moved to vecOne and {90, 100} to stay in vecTwo.

Initial:

```
v1 = {}; 
v2 = {60, 70, 80, 90, 100}
```

i = 2

```
v1 = {80};
v2 = {60, 70, 100, 90}
```

i = 1

```
v1 = {80, 70};
v2 = {60, 90, 100}
```

i = 0

```
v1 = {80, 70, 60}
v2 = {100, 90}
```

To solve it you need to check if the size of vecTwo is not even and just push it to vecOne and skip moving and popping back in vecTwo.

```
int i = (size - 1) / 2
if (size % 2 != 0)  // if not even
{
    vecOne.push_back(vecTwo[i]);
    --i;
}

while(i != 0)
{
    // do what you do now in the for loop
}

if (size % 2 != 0) vecTwo.pop_back(); // if we skipped one pop it now
```